# I am trying to install kivy package(kivy-deps.angle) on mac but it fails and give me this details:

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, kivy, pypi

Collecting kivy-deps.angle

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy-deps.angle (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for kivy-deps.angle

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this project only publishes built distributions for Windows platforms. Note that https://pypi.org/project/kivy-deps.angle/0.2.0/#files only contains `win32.whl` and `win_amd64.whl` distributions. It will only be installable on Windows.

Comment: Thank you.Ive installed kivy and I tried running it on my mac but if i run it ,it displays, '[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Text provider, abort.'.I'm so fustrated .Please any help?